# Parse API request count and Batching: saveAll() destroyAll() etc

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

There have been many questions asked on this topic but I have found a lot of contradictory answers which I believe is due to the the way the Parse.com's terms of usage has varied over the years.

I want to know how batch request such as `saveAll()` and `destroyAll()` impact the API usage count. One would naturally assume this single call would count for 1 API request, however based on my usage numbers I can see in the Analytics Dashboard it appears that this is not the case.

e.g I save N objects in a `saveAll()` request. It looks like this is using N API requests.

Can anyone confirm this is the case in their own projects? If not perhaps I am using these batch request incorrectly.

FYI this is from the Parse Official FAQ but isn't 100% transparent:

> Batched requests will be counted based on the number of operations
>   performed in each batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch is code and network efficient in that you make 1 call, but that one call is composed of a number of individual requests which are unpacked and run on the server. As such the API count is the number of packed requests, not the single container request.